# Notifications don't show up (notify-send notify-osd)

Tags: notifications, dbus, notify-osd

Notifications via notify-send and notify-osd stopped working for me for no apparent reason.
notify-send does not display anything.
notify-osd displays this error:

```
** (notify-osd:30409): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-JOB9rCGFAt: Connection refused

** (notify-osd:30409): WARNING **: dbus_create_service_instance(): Got error "Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-GWnKyuCbfH: Connection refused"


** (notify-osd:30409): WARNING **: Could not register instance
```

This used to work just fine for me before, so maybe it's some recent change in Debian?
I also have my own script to set DBUS related environment, but it no longer works with this as well:

```
session="$HOME/.dbus/session-bus/$(dbus-uuidgen --get)-$(echo $DISPLAY | sed -e 's/\([^:]*:\)//g' -e 's/\..*$//g')"
if [ -e $session ] ; then
  . $session
fi
```

Any idea how to troubleshoot? I did not find anything recent via google.
Thanks.
m.